# __autoload and exception friendship issue

Tags: php, exception, autoload

Well, I'm developing a framework and I'm working with `__autoload` classes and `exception`. The problem is that on [PHP 5.2 you can't catch exceptions inside __autoload](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZEdRWI). I need catch them, there are some way to do it? *[PHP 5.3 it works fine!](http://codepad.viper-7.com/R2A9MP)*

On my framework, you have a folder that contains some classes, but the user can try load some class that not exists. The correct way is test if `class_exists`, but I wan't make it optional, if user want work with exceptions. For instance:

```
$obj = new NotFoundClass();
```

In this example, if debug mode of framework is on, the client will be launched to an error page, explain about this problem (*the class NotFoundClass is not found in class dir*). Then *only* if user don't catch manually this problem, I'll launch to a internal error page, that tell client about this uncatched problem.

My current code is that, you can check full code on my [github page](https://github.com/david-proweb/core) or directly in [the problematic file](https://github.com/david-proweb/core/blob/12100a6355ae87a089de45bb81c4198583d4ab8f/modules/core/classes/core.php#L15) for better understanding. I don't know if I'm clear here, please talk to me in this case.

Comment: On first sight I would say: not possible. Looking into `spl_autoload_register` might give you more options probably.

Comment: It's used like `spl_autoload_register( 'core::__autoload' );`, I guess that it is impossible on PHP 5.2.

Comment: I know that it's used similiary. However you can register more than one and you can control which one comes last. The last one can fake a class defintion and throw the exception on the objects constructor. That would mimic the PHP 5.3 behaviour.

Comment: nice idea @hakre , however it won't work for static calls without previous object instantiation.

Comment: Yeah! I found exactly this problem... And too, strangely, is impossible catch this *fake* exception on PHP 5.2! :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code in question:

```
 $obj = new NotFoundClass();
```

you can do it the following:

```
function __autoload($className) {
    $message = sprintf("Class '%s' not found.", $className);
    if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0)
        throw new Exception($message);
    else{
        eval("class $className {public function __construct() {
            throw new Exception(\"$message\");
        } }");
    }
}

$obj = new NotFoundClass();
```

Which will make it throwing the exception regardless if it's PHP 5.2 or 5.3; [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VsCAa9).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, from your question:

> on PHP 5.2 you can't catch exceptions inside __autoload

The best you can do is to redirect user / do something with this error on your own, but not to let user decide what to do.

Example code to redirect user:

```
function missing_class_fatal_error_handler(){
    global $missing_class;
    header('Location: error_page.php?missing_class='.$missing_class);
}

function __autoload($class){
    if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0)
        throw new Exception("EXCEPTION: Class '$class' not found\n");
    else{
        global $missing_class;
        $missing_class = $class;
        register_shutdown_function('missing_class_fatal_error_handler');
    }
}
try{
    $x = new missingclass();
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage(); // PHP 5.3
}
echo "this will not execute under php < 5.3";
```

Comment: Yeah, maybe the best option is not throw, launch a fatal error instead, at least inside of `__autoload` method.